# Loading a custom URL scheme on iPhone from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, url-scheme

I have an application that uses `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to modify HTML that I have no access to (like Greasemonkey). Specifically, I want to store the username and password from a login form in `NSUserDefaults` when the `onSubmit` event is fired from JS.

I already have a custom URL scheme and an `onSubmit` handler. I can pass the URL a username and password, and it will store it. I am only having issues with the `onSubmit` handler: how can I save data with my custom URL before submitting the form?

I am **not** using any Javascript frameworks, and my code only targets Mobile Safari.

Comment: Not the answer you want (hence this being a comment), but you should really, really store your password in the keychain, **not** `NSUserDefaults`. Otherwise you're just asking for the kind of trouble Skype just got in to with their Android app. If you're storing user passwords, you should encrypt them.

Comment: @lxt I wasn't aware of the keychain or security implications of `NSUserDefaults`, so thanks for pointing that out. I also might not store passwords if I can't do it securely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for not directly answering your question, but I think you may want to consider an easier option.  You should be able to sniff a form submission without injecting any javascript into the `UIWebView`.  Just implement something like this in your `UIWebViewDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"https://www.thirdpartysite.com/theirLoginScript"]) {
        NSString *username = [self parseUsernameFromRequest:request];
        NSString *password = [self parsePasswordFromRequest:request];
        [self saveUsername:username andPassword:password];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I've left the implementations of `parseUsernameFromRequest:`, `parsePasswordFromRequest:`, and `saveUsername:andPassword:` to your imagination.

(Hint: If the form uses the GET method, then you can get its parameters using `[[request URL] parameterString]`.  If the form uses the POST method, then you can use `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`.)

By the way, you should never store sensitive information like passwords in NSUserDefaults.  Apple provides Keychain Services for storing this type of information securely.  Unfortunately working with the Keychain Services is surprisingly complex, so you may want to check out Buzz Andersen's [Simple iPhone Keychain Code](http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful link to the Keychain wrapper, and the sample code. On an https connection, does form sniffing still work?

Comment: It should.  It's not really "sniffing" at the transport level.  Your app's just monitoring its own web view.